# Set focus component in popup of ADF

Tags: javascript, java, oracle-adf, adf-task-flow

How can I set focus to a component in my fragment page that is used like a popup?

(I use in task-flow, ADF component.) For example, focus to  `<af:panelBox />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    document.getElementById("firstName").focus();
```

This code focus to the choosen component.